# Grep - ^(\s*$) vs ^\s*$

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

I want to search for a field that only has spaces. When counting, this two commands gave me different results:

```
grep "^\s*$" -E -c
grep "^(\s*$)" -E -c
```

Another thing. What is the correct way to say "spaces only or other thing":

```
grep "^(\s*$|STRING)" -E -c
```

or

```
grep "(^\s*$|^STRING)" -E -c
```

Or they are equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain `grep` doesn't understand `\s` or parentheses.(*)  You want `grep -P` if available, or `grep -E`/`egrep` and write `\s` out as `[ ^I]` (where `^I` is <kbd>Tab</kbd>; `grep` without `-P` doesn't understand `\t` either).  Additionally, with double quotes some shells will process the `\s` and leave behind just `s`; you should always use single quotes with regexes from the shell, except for when you actually need to interpolate a variable (e.g. something like `'^\s*'"$foo"'\s+\('`, switching quoting in mid-parameter).

The alternatives in your second example (again, with `-P` and single quoting instead of double) do the same thing.  The former is technically better because `grep` won't backtrack as much, but practically it won't matter.

(*) pedantry:  backslashed parens will work, again requiring single quoting so the shell doesn't eat the backslashes.  `egrep` is usually easier.

Comment: While the general advice to use single quotes is right, in this particular case, it doesn't matter: `)` and `|` are not single-character variables, so the shell won't interpolate `$)` or `$|`; and `"\s"` expands to `\s`, the backslash inside double quotes is retained except before `"$\\``.

Comment: @geekosaur I was using the -E option but i forgot to include it here. I will edit the post. 

In this case why the two options give me different results?

The single vs double-quotes can influence this?

Comment: @Gilles: that turns out to depend on the shell; I've just gotten 3 different behaviors from three different shells.

Comment: @user6678: see my reply to Gilles; it depends on the shell (but it appears that in `bash` the double quotes should be okay; it's still a bad habit that can lead to problems in the future, though). `\s` is not supported by `grep -E` in any version of GNU `grep` I have available (checked on OSX and Ubuntu Maverick). That said, I would expect them to behave the same (if incorrectly), and they do so here.

Comment: @geekosaur: What shells are those? On Debian, I can't find a (Bourne-style) shell that prints anything but `\a$|` for `printf %s\\n "\a$|"`. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_02_03) is clear that the backslash must be retained; I can't find anything about `$` followed by an invalid character.

Comment: Thanks guys. 

As i searched i found another way to do it:
`grep -E '^[[:space:]]*$'`

Comment: Newer versions of *plain grep* actually do understand `\s`. `grep -c '\s' <<<' '` == 1.